# String in directory

Tags: c#, string

I am defining a string called `Folder` and am using it in a directory.
Would I just use `C:\Windows\%Folder%\...` or would I call the string differently?  I have never really used directories instead of namespaces in C#, and I am wondering how to do this.

Comment: It's *really* unclear what you're trying to do at the moment. Do you mean you have a string *variable* called `Folder`? I don't see what namespaces have to do with it, either...

Comment: Your question is **extremely** unclear.

Comment: Please edit this to make it more clear what you're trying to do. We'll try to help out.

Comment: I am trying to use a string in a direcectory path, for example, in Batch, it would look like C:\Windows\%Folder%\... I mean to use the string defined in SET Folder=System32, how would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're wondering about concatenating folders in C# (and it seems like you are based on your comment clarifying the question), you should really be using [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) instead of raw string concatenation.

Example:

```
using System.IO;

string Folder = "System32";
string FullPath = Path.Combine("C:/Windows", Folder);
```

this results in `FullPath` being `"C:/Windows/System32"`, or whatever the OS uses to separate folder names.

Answer (score 1):

```
var folder=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Folder");
var path=Path.Combine(root, folder);
```

Comment: Okay, but, how would I use the variable "Folder" as part of my directory name?

Comment: @ZacHeimgartner: `root` is a relative parent folder, can be assigned with string.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your asking how to concatenate strings:

```
"something" + someVariable + "something else"
```